# docker pull centos timeout on windows 8.1

Tags: windows, docker

When I run from command line

```
docker pull centos
```

I got timeout error. I have no proxy and try from different networks and stucked on this. What reason can be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you wrote that you use Windows 8 I assume that you run *boot2docker*?

Can you first verify that you can connect to *boot2docker* itself? E.g. with `docker ps`? If you still get timeouts issuing that command, make sure *boot2docker* is running by typing `boot2docker restart`.

If you can connect to *boot2docker* without any problems and the `docker pull centos` problem remains then it seems you have other kind of networking problems on your site which block your connections.

Comment: Yep, It helps. But for now looks like docker pull is ok, but vagrant up with this container is timeout. Could you help me?

Comment: Could you please ask a separate question specific to that new vagrant topic including some details on your vagrant configuration?

Comment: Sorry I decide to decline my idea about vagrant + docker enviroment. It's a pain to configure it on Windows %)